# present simple or progressive?

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

If I am talking to a friend and he sends me a video, I see someone in the video doing something. And I want to write my friend about that person. Should I use the present simple or present progressive?

For example, If that person is riding a bike, should I say *he rides so fast* or *he is riding so fast* ?

Comment: He is riding so fast [in the video]. Reminder: Simple present is only for general statements. He rides so fast when he races.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable. It just depends on what you want to say! “He rides so fast” is a general statement about the person in the video. “He is riding so fast” is a statement about the person’s actions in that specific video.